# overloaded templated functions ambiguity issue

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, overloading

Could anyone find a difference between 1st overload and required function? If I comment out Python specification, compilation is fine, but I need it elsewhere. Totally maddening...

```
template<typename TN>
void fromVectorTo(const std::vector<TN> & input, xlw::impl::XlfOper<xlw::LPXLFOPER> * output){....}
template<typename TN>
void fromVectorTo(const std::vector<TN> & input, PyObject ** output){...}

error C2665: 'pal::fromVectorTo' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types
8>        myPython.h(73): could be 'void pal::fromVectorTo<double>(const std::vector<_Ty> &,PyObject **)'
8>        with
8>        [
8>            _Ty=double
8>        ]
8>        myXLW.h(102): or       'void pal::fromVectorTo<double>(const std::vector<_Ty> &,xlw::impl::XlfOper<LPOPER_TYPE> *)'
8>        with
8>        [
8>            _Ty=double,
8>            LPOPER_TYPE=xlw::LPXLFOPER
8>        ]
8>        while trying to match the argument list '(const std::vector<_Ty>, xlw::impl::XlfOper<LPOPER_TYPE> *)'
8>        with
8>        [
8>            _Ty=double
8>        ]
8>        and
8>        [
8>            LPOPER_TYPE=xlw::LPXLFOPER
8>        ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was a compiler bug - the error message must have been wrong. Issue seems to go away when I used partical specialisation of template classes + did other modifs.